# Microsoft Teams Error: error code - caa70007

Tags: authentication, microsoft-teams

Not being able to log in . Even after uninstalling and reinstalling. Facing error with code:caa70007

Answer (score 1):

Update: Flushing DNS Cache worked for me. After searching for a while I found a solution for this.
Just run "CMD" as administrator.
**Type: pconfig/flushdns**
Link: https://www.phonereporters.com/2020/05/fix-microsoft-teams-error-code-caa7000a/